# Adjusting Bar width in Maplotlib Pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Want to adjust the bar width if plotting for only single data set. Any suggestions or help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
name = ['Windows']
count = [9]
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), squeeze=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.136, right=0.87, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
plt.barh(name, width=count, label=name, align='center')
title = ax.set_title("Operating Systems", position=(.5, 1.02), bbox={'facecolor': '0.8', 'pad': 5})
for index, value in enumerate(count):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value))
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

Actual Bar Plot
[image: Actual Bar Plot]

Desired Bar Plot
[image: Desired Bar Plot]

Comment: You can use `plt.ylim(-1, 3)` to show more of the plot than just the single bar. By the way, adding a space before the text could make it more readable `plt.text(value, index, ' '+str(value))`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be this:

```
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
plt.barh(name, width=count, height=1, label=name, align='center')
```